# How to logically organize recurring tasks?

Tags: calendar, logic, task

What's the best way to create recurring tasks?

Should I create some special syntax and parse it, kind of similar to Cronjobs on Linux or should I much rather just use a cronjob that runs every hour to create more of those recurring tasks with no end?

Keep in mind, that you can have endless recurring tasks and tasks with an enddate.

Answer (score 1):

[Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is an open source job scheduling system that uses cron expressions to control the periodicity of the job executions.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is always "minimum effort for maximum effect" (or best bang per buck).

If it can be done with cron, why not use cron?  I'd consider it wasted effort to re-implement cron just for the fun of it so, unless you really need features that cron doesn't have, stick with it.